# MySQL Optimizing long IN statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of items called PARENTTABLE (id,...)

I also have a table of items called CHILDTABLE (id,parent_id,...)
with a reference column to items in the PARENTTABLE.

How can I write a query that only gets items from PARENTTABLE that definitely have items with a reference in CHILDTABLE.

Currently I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM PARENTTABLE WHERE id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM CHILDTABLE)
```

Is this an acceptable method, or is there an more optimized approach since over time there will end up being many entries into the CHILDTABLE making the IN statement very long.

Comment: without further information this is a generic SQL question as best. The sollution will be a JOIN in the sql statement.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PARENTTABLE.* 
FROM PARENTTABLE
INNER JOIN CHILDTABLE ON CHILDTABLE.parent = PARENTTABLE.id
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
SELECT * from parent where id in (Select distinct parentid from child)
```

Answer (score 1):

A version with `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM parenttable p
 WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM childtable
   WHERE parent_id = p.id
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e85636/1)** demo